# How to ensure that a big file (blob) is released from memory in ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, garbage-collection

I have an app which receives an incoming file (attachment in the form of blob_data), and just passes it on, to another external service/API (while storing the attachment metadata in my app). I don't need to store the blob_data in my app.

```
class Attachment < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :blob_data
end
```

When I call `@attachment.save` I presume the blob_data won't be persisted to the DB, because it is an attr_accessor field. But, is there a way to ensure that this blob_data is released from memory immediately? I don't want the blob_data lingering around until the GC catches it at a later time, as it may take up quite a bit of memory, especially if the server receives several requests in the same time period.

Would it be as simple as using `@attachment.blob_data = nil`? Will this have any effect on the immediacy of the GC catching it? Is there a better way?

Comment: Ruby can actually stream files directly without storing them in memory. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523039/how-to-destroy-ruby-object) post, the only thing you can do is remove all references to `blob_data` and wait for garbage collection to kick in. As the post and @max's comment both mention, a more efficient way of solving your problem would be to stream the file without storing it in memory.