# How are virtual attributes managed in memory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, memory-management, computed-properties, virtual-attribute

I'm going through Michael Hartl's [rails tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/advanced_login) and have come to a point where he defines a virtual attribute, `remember_token` and later assigns a value to it in a `remember` instance method:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  attr_accessor :remember_token
  ...

  def remember
    self.remember_token = User.new_token
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, User.digest(remember_token))
  end
end
```

He then accesses the value of the virtual attribute in a helper method after `remember` is called:

```
def remember(user)
  user.remember
  cookies.permanent.signed[:user_id] = user.id
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = user.remember_token
end
```

My interpretation was that after the `remember` method is executed (and where `remember_token` is assigned it's removed from memory. Obviously this isn't the case here because it's still available to use when assigning a new value to `cookies.permanent[:remember_token]`.

I guess my source of confusion stems from data persistence. Assuming that the `remember_token` is made into an instance variable with the help of `attr_accessor`, when does it officially become unavailable?

Comment: When the object goes away. Instance methods never "become unavailable", they are part of the object on which they're defined.

Comment: I'm sorry. Maybe not the *instance methods* per se but the value that the instance method produces.

Comment: Those values are garbage collected like any other value. As long as there is a reference to them, they won't be deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your assumption is wrong.

"Virtual attributes" is really just a term used for plain old instance attributes in models to differentiate from the database backed attributes that are persisted.

Instance attributes retain their value as long as the object which encapsulates them exists (or you explicitly nil the value). The object exists until the garbage collector [can determine that it is no longer referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19523039/how-to-destroy-ruby-object).

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def initialize(name: nil)
    @name = name
    # or using the accessor
    self.name = name
  end
end
```

So if we create an instance of `Person` it will of course retain the value of `name`:

```
jane = Person.new(name: 'Jane')
jane.name # => 'Jane'
```

What you might be confusing is local variables which are only available in the block where they are defined:

```
class Person
  attr_accessor :name

  def say_hello
    # this local variable is garbage collect after the method is called
    phrase =  "Hello, my name is "
    puts phrase + name # we can omit self since it is implied
  end
end
```

Comment: "Assuming that the remember_token is made into an instance variable with the help of attr_accessor" is also wrong - attr_accessor creates a setter and getter method by meta programming. It does not declare instance variables. The instance variable is created whenever it is assigned a value.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I must ask though, did you mean to put `name` instead of `bar` in your explanation?

Comment: Oops yes I did mean name.